# IOS UICollectionView with Paging Enabled pushed off center

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]I have a collection View that is horizontally scrolling. I checked off paging enabled in storyboard. Everything is working fine however when i scroll through the cell on the first and last cell i can scroll just a little extra and move the cell off center. Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT
I added a screenshot, the cell is the gray and the white is the collection view background, that acts as a page and when i drag it just a little that the whit is gone that acts as its own page as well, however the cells that arent first or last dont have this issue

Comment: Does "cell" mean "page"?

Comment: I have two questions 
1. Is Paging enabled or disables?
2. Add the screenshot of the UI where you are facing the problem.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot?

Comment: @almas I attached the screen shots

Comment: @sharpkits Updated with screen shots